# Adding a new column of type Int32 to a julia dataframe using map

Tags: julia

I have a string column data with values like `2.323456` and I want to create a new column with an Int32 value like this: `2323456`.

I have tried to create a new column using `df[!, :newcolumn]` and `map` function, using also `parse` to parse the string into an *Int32*.

This works.

However, when I execute an additional transformation with map, it is converted to *Int64*.

This is my input data:

```
julia> df2 = DataFrame(low_str=["1.12345", "1.12346", "1.12347"]);

julia> pretty_table(df2, markdown)
| low_str |
|  String |
|---------|
| 1.12345 |
| 1.12346 |
| 1.12347 |
```

I want to convert that to Int32. So I do:

```
julia> df2[!, :low] = map(x -> parse( Int32, string( x[1],x[3:7]) ),   df2[:, :low_str]);

julia> pretty_table(df2, markdown)
| low_str |    low |
|  String |  Int32 |
|---------|--------|
| 1.12345 | 112345 |
| 1.12346 | 112346 |
| 1.12347 | 112347 |
```

So far so good.
Now I want to apply a round down so I do:

```
julia> df2[!, :low] = map( x -> x - mod(x,5), df2[:, :low]);

julia> pretty_table(df2, markdown)
| low_str |    low |
|  String |  Int64 |
|---------|--------|
| 1.12345 | 112345 |
| 1.12346 | 112345 |
| 1.12347 | 112345 |
```

The data is rounded down correctly **but it is now of type Int64** instead of the intended Int32.

**How can I preserve the Int32?**

Comment: in general you do not have to use `map` or `map!` much these days. Most of the things can be done using broadcasting and broadcasting assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it (and at the same time in-place, so it is fast) is:

```
df2.low .-= mod.(df2.low, 5)
```

If you want to use `map!` then something like this produces you the desired result:

```
map!(x -> x - mod(x,5), df2.low, df2.low)
```